# What would be a good implementation to get all Monday and Thursday dates Between a given date range (DateX and DateY) in JAVA

Tags: java, date, range

I want to get some days between a given range of dates. What would be an optimal solution for this? For example, I want to get all Monday, Wednesday and Thursday dates from today up to two months.

Comment: Is this homework? It smells like homework :D

Comment: sure does... and it's not really that hard.

Comment: I would start with the simplest solution which is to step through each day and pick out the days you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes.

Instantiate `List` objects to collect your results.

```
List<LocalDate> mondays = new ArrayList<>() ;
List<LocalDate> wednesdays = new ArrayList<>() ;
List<LocalDate> thursdays = new ArrayList<>() ;
```

Determine today's date. This requires a time zone, as the date varies around the globe by zone for any given moment.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ;
```

Add two more months. The java.time classes smartly handle the issue of shorter/longer months. Read the class doc to see if you agree with their behavior/policies.

```
LocalDate twoMonthsLater = today.plusMonths( 2 );
```

Loop each date, incrementing one day at a time. Test its day-of-week value using the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum. Note that you can `switch` on an [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) object, but oddly cannot include its class name prefix. So we use `MONDAY` rather than my preferred `DayOfWeek.MONDAY`.

```
LocalDate localDate = today ;
while ( localDate.isBefore( twoMonthsLater ) ) {
    DayOfWeek dow = localDate.getDayOfWeek() ;
     switch ( dow ) {
            case MONDAY: 
                mondays.add( localDate ) ;
                break;

            case WEDNESDAY: 
                wednesdays.add( localDate ) ;
                break;

            case THURSDAY:
                thursdays.add( localDate ) ;
                break;

            default: 
                // Ignore any other day-of-week.
                break;
        }
        // Set-up the next loop. Increment by one day at a time.
        localDate = localDate.plusDays( 1 ) ;
}
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "From " + today + " to " + twoMonthsLater + ":"  );
System.out.println( "mondays: " + mondays ) ;
System.out.println( "wednesdays: " + wednesdays ) ;
System.out.println( "thursdays: " + thursdays ) ;
```

See [this code run live at IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/CeLHtB).

> From 2017-10-17 to 2017-12-17:
>
> mondays: [2017-10-23, 2017-10-30, 2017-11-06, 2017-11-13, 2017-11-20, 2017-11-27, 2017-12-04, 2017-12-11]
>
> wednesdays: [2017-10-18, 2017-10-25, 2017-11-01, 2017-11-08, 2017-11-15, 2017-11-22, 2017-11-29, 2017-12-06, 2017-12-13]
>
> thursdays: [2017-10-19, 2017-10-26, 2017-11-02, 2017-11-09, 2017-11-16, 2017-11-23, 2017-11-30, 2017-12-07, 2017-12-14]

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: How counting weeks result in counting a specific DayOfWeek?
`long mondayCount = ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between( 01/10/2017, 31/10/2017 );`
I just tested and mondayCount = 4 for OCT/2017, which has 5 Mondays,

Comment: @FiruzzZ You really should open a Question for a tangent, but… To quote the JavaDoc: *For the ISO calendar system, it is equal to 7 days.*. So ( 31 / 7 ) = 4.4…, which means four (4) full weeks. The term “week” is quite ambiguous, so always read the documentation carefully to see if your meaning lines up with their meaning. If you want standard ISO 8601 Monday-based weeks, see the week-based year classes `IsoFields` in Java 8 & 9, and [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) in the *ThreeTen-Extra* project.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the number of weeks between x and y, and take x's weekday into account.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`java.util.Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html). One can get a instance of it, set it to a given date, then, for example, call `get(DAY_OF_WEEK)` on it. Also it has some nice methods to get number of day in a given year and number of days in a given year.